# Spring Batch: not able to access jobexecutionConext in flatfileitemwriter

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

hey i am trying to use the jobexecutioncontxt in my flatfileitemwriter and it shows me errors...

My xml is:-

```
<batch:job id="subrogationJob" incrementer="incrementer">
    <batch:step id="subrogation" next="readFromDataBase">
        <batch:tasklet ref="filetransferTasklet">
            <batch:listeners>
                <batch:listener ref="setCurrentFile" />
            </batch:listeners>
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
    <batch:step id="readFromDataBase" next="hasMoreFilesStep">
        <batch:tasklet>
            <batch:chunk reader="databaseReader" processor="subrogationProcessor" writer="dbToFileItemWriter"
                commit-interval="1" />
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
    <batch:decision id="hasMoreFilesStep" decider="hasMoreFilesDecider">
        <batch:fail on="FAILED" />
        <batch:next on="CONTINUE" to="subrogation" />
        <batch:end on="COMPLETED"/>
    </batch:decision>
</batch:job>

<bean
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations"
        value="file:${UNIQUE_DIR}/${APP_NAME}/batch/nonadj_batch.properties" />
</bean>



<bean id="incrementer"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.RunIdIncrementer" />

<bean id="setCurrentFile"
    class="com.hcsc.ccsp.nonadj.subrogation.batch.SubrogationInputFolderScanner"
    scope="step">
    <property name="collectionParameter" value="inputFiles" />
    <property name="outputFolder" value="${subrogationOutputFolder}" />
    <property name="inputFolder" value="${subrogationInputFolder}" />
    <property name="archiveFolder" value="${subrogationArchiveFolder}" />
</bean>

<bean id="filetransferTasklet"
    class="com.hcsc.ccsp.nonadj.subrogation.integration.SubrogationFileTransferTasklet"
    scope="step">
    <property name="inputfile" value="file:#{jobExecutionContext['inputFile']}" />
    <property name="outputfile" value="file:#{jobExecutionContext['outputFile']}" />
</bean>

<bean id="subrogationProcessor" class="com.hcsc.ccsp.nonadj.subrogation.processor.SubrogationProcessor" scope="step">

 </bean>

 <bean id="dbToFileItemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter" scope="step">
    <property name="resource" value="file:#{jobExecutionContext['outputFile']}" />
    <property name="lineAggregator">
        <bean class="com.hcsc.ccsp.nonadj.subrogation.writer.SubrogationLineAggregator"/>
    </property>
    <property name="footerCallback" ref="subroHeaderFooterWriter" />
    <property name="headerCallback" ref="subroHeaderFooterWriter" />
    <property name="transactional" value="true" />

    <property name="appendAllowed" value="true" /> 
    <property name="saveState" value="true" />
</bean>
<bean id="subroHeaderFooterWriter" class="com.hcsc.ccsp.nonadj.subrogation.writer.SubrogationHeaderFooterWriter" scope="step">
    <property name="delegate" ref="dbToFileItemWriter" />
</bean>

<bean id="hasMoreFilesDecider"
    class="com.hcsc.ccsp.nonadj.subrogation.batch.CollectionEmptyDecider" scope="step">
    <property name="collectionParameter" value="inputFiles" />
    <property name="outputfile" value="file:#{jobExecutionContext['outputFile']}" />
    <property name="archiveFolder" value="file:${subrogationArchiveFolder}" />
</bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.hcsc.ccsp.nonadj.subrogation.batch"
    use-default-filters="false">
    <context:include-filter type="annotation"
        expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Component" />
</context:component-scan>

<context:annotation-config />

<bean id="databaseReader"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader"
    scope="step">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="subrogrationDataSource" />
    <property name="sql"
        value="SELECT QUERY" />
    <property name="rowMapper">
        <bean
            class="com.hcsc.ccsp.nonadj.subrogation.integration.SubrogationFieldSetMapper" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

in my listner in beforestep i put parameter in jobcontextn as

ExecutionContext jobContext = stepExecution.getJobExecution().getExecutionContext();
jobContext.put("outputFile", filePath);

and in xml when i m trying to use this in xml in my writer is shows me error.....
but it works fine filetransferTasklet.

error is :-

```
                                                 O inside reader
[5/1/14 10:41:02:303 CDT] 0000001a SystemOut     O inside processor........
[5/1/14 10:41:02:303 CDT] 0000001a SystemOut     O inside aggregator
[5/1/14 10:41:02:320 CDT] 0000001a AbstractStep  E org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep execute Exception while closing step execution resources
                                 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.subroHeaderFooterWriter' defined in class path resource [subrogation.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type '$Proxy46 implementing org.springframework.batch.item.file.ResourceAwareItemWriterItemStream,org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean,java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.aop.scope.ScopedObject,org.springframework.aop.framework.AopInfrastructureBean,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised' to required type 'org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter' for property 'delegate'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [$Proxy46 implementing org.springframework.batch.item.file.ResourceAwareItemWriterItemStream,org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean,java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.aop.scope.ScopedObject,org.springframework.aop.framework.AopInfrastructureBean,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised] to required type [org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter] for property 'delegate': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$2.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:329)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope.get(StepScope.java:150)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:33)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:182)
    at $Proxy47.writeFooter(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter.close(FlatFileItemWriter.java:282)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy46.close(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemStream.close(CompositeItemStream.java:83)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.close(TaskletStep.java:297)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:264)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:135)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:60)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:124)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:135)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:293)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:120)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:48)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:114)
    at com.hcsc.ccsp.nonadj.batch.web.JobLauncherController.launch(JobLauncherController.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:426)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:718)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1661)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:937)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:500)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3826)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:276)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:931)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1583)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:186)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:455)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:384)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:272)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1550)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type '$Proxy46 implementing org.springframework.batch.item.file.ResourceAwareItemWriterItemStream,org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean,java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.aop.scope.ScopedObject,org.springframework.aop.framework.AopInfrastructureBean,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised' to required type 'org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter' for property 'delegate'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [$Proxy46 implementing org.springframework.batch.item.file.ResourceAwareItemWriterItemStream,org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean,java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.aop.scope.ScopedObject,org.springframework.aop.framework.AopInfrastructureBean,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised] to required type [org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter] for property 'delegate': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:462)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:499)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:493)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.convertForProperty(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1371)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1330)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    ... 70 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [$Proxy46 implementing org.springframework.batch.item.file.ResourceAwareItemWriterItemStream,org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean,java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.aop.scope.ScopedObject,org.springframework.aop.framework.AopInfrastructureBean,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised] to required type [org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter] for property 'delegate': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:231)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:447)
    ... 76 more

[5/1/14 10:41:02:386 CDT] 0000001a AbstractJob   E org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob execute Encountered fatal error executing job
                                 org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecutionException: Flow execution ended unexpectedly
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:141)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:293)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:120)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:48)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:114)
    at com.hcsc.ccsp.nonadj.batch.web.JobLauncherController.launch(JobLauncherController.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:426)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:718)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1661)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:937)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:500)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3826)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:276)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:931)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1583)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:186)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:455)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:384)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:272)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1550)
Caused by: org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowExecutionException: Ended flow=subrogationJob at state=subrogationJob.hasMoreFilesStep with exception
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:152)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:124)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:135)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.hasMoreFilesDecider': Scope 'step' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No context holder available for step scope
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:339)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:33)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:182)
    at $Proxy45.decide(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.DecisionState.handle(DecisionState.java:43)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.xml.SimpleFlowFactoryBean$DelegateState.handle(SimpleFlowFactoryBean.java:141)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:144)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No context holder available for step scope
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope.getContext(StepScope.java:197)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope.get(StepScope.java:139)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325)
    ... 49 more

[5/1/14 10:41:02:392 CDT] 0000001a SimpleJobLaun I org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1 run Job: [FlowJob: [name=subrogationJob]] completed with the following parameters: [{param47=47}] and the following status: [FAILED]
```

SubrogationHeaderFooterWriter is

```
 package com.hcsc.ccsp.nonadj.subrogation.writer;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.Writer;
    import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
    import org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileFooterCallback;
    import org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileHeaderCallback;
    import org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter;
    import com.hcsc.ccsp.nonadj.subrogation.batch.Subrogation;
    import com.hcsc.ccsp.nonadj.subrogation.integration.SubrogationFileTransferTasklet;
    import com.hcsc.ccsp.nonadj.subrogation.processor.SubrogationProcessor;

    public class SubrogationHeaderFooterWriter implements  
        FlatFileFooterCallback, FlatFileHeaderCallback{

        SubrogationFileTransferTasklet fileTransferTasklet = new SubrogationFileTransferTasklet();

        private FlatFileItemWriter<Subrogation> delegate;

        public void setDelegate(FlatFileItemWriter<Subrogation> delegate) {
            this.delegate = delegate;
        }

        public FlatFileItemWriter<Subrogation> getDelegate() {
            return delegate;
        }

        /*@Override
        public void open(ExecutionContext executionContext)
                throws ItemStreamException {

            this.delegate.open(executionContext);

        }

        @Override
        public void update(ExecutionContext executionContext)
                throws ItemStreamException {

            this.delegate.update(executionContext);
        }

        @Override
        public void close() throws ItemStreamException {

            this.delegate.close();
        }*/

        @Override
        public void writeHeader(Writer writer) throws IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("inside header");
            writer.write(SubrogationFileTransferTasklet.header);

        }

        @Override
        public void writeFooter(Writer writer) throws IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            System.out.println("inside header");
            String trailer = SubrogationFileTransferTasklet.trailer;
            String s1 = StringUtils.substring(trailer, 0, 23);
            System.out.println("trailer without contwer is" + s1);

            System.out.println("whole traileer is" + s1
                    + SubrogationProcessor.totalRecords);
            System.out
                    .println("duplicate data is" + SubrogationProcessor.duplicate);
            writer.write(s1 + SubrogationProcessor.totalRecords);

            System.out.println("inside Footer");

            writer.write("Total Number of Records :: \n\n");    

        }

        /*public void write(List<? extends Subrogation> subrogation) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("inside writer");

            delegate.write(subrogation);

        }*/

    }
```

pls help....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two exceptions here.  The first one is due to the fact that the type for `com.hcsc.ccsp.nonadj.subrogation.writer.SubrogationHeaderFooterWriter.delegate` does not match the FlatFileItemWriter.  What type is that defined as (if you can update your post with the code for this class, it would be helpful)?

The second one is because you are attempting to use a decider that is step scoped.  In a regular Spring Batch job (not a JSR-352 based job), a decider is not a step.  Because of that, it doesn't get a StepExecution, and therefore step scope is not supported.

**Update**

Change your setter for the delegate to take `ItemWriter` (the interface) instead of `FlatFileItemWriter` (the implementation) to address the first issue.

Comment: pls review my edited question...
thank u for ur answer for 2nd error i solved it after removing scope="step"...
pls help me with the firs one......thank u

Comment: hey....thank u so much it works fine.......
but i have a question that.....
when i was using the property file to get the outputfile location it works fine with the FlatFileItemWriter.......
but why it not works with the jobExecutionContext....???

Comment: Probably because with the properties file, the `FlatFileItemWriter` wasn't step scoped so the type was available.  With it step scoped, only the interfaces it implements are available so Spring didn't know what to do.